# wampserver is preventing me from changing config files

Tags: php, notepad++, wampserver

i have windows 7 home premium 64bit.

So i decided to try out some php, so i downloaded wampserver.  First, i tried to change the index file in the www directory, but even when i quit wampserver by right clicking and clicking exit on the wampserver icon, notepad++ says the file is still open in an other application.

So i tried following [this tutorial (How to create a Virtual Host in WampServer)](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,124482) but i cant edit the httpd-vhosts.conf file because of the same issue.

thanks in advance

PS:clicking *"stop all services"* doesnt work either.

**edit:**
computer restart did not resolve my issue.

notepad says access denied when trying to save the file.

permissions are read/write

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again (Windows)?

Comment: no, not yet, but i dont want to restart windows for every edit

Comment: Are you sure you have the right to edit the file ? Might be Windows preventing you to edit the file because you're not administrator. Try to change the write restrictions

Comment: i have the right to edit the file, the tutorial is written by the makers of the software.

Comment: At least try a restart, it might be that some other program is still running and locking the files and that a restart will fix it forever for you. :)

Comment: If you have a Total Commander or FileZilla or other similar SW, open up your `www` folder in it and check that the files you want to edit have at least 755 permissions. If not, change to 755, if yes, change to 777 and try again. This seems weird to me as I have almost the same setup (Win 7 Ultimate) and never had had such issue...

Comment: Exit wampserver and run again by right clicking the wampserver and choose `run as administrator`. Then you should be able to stop and start the services.

Comment: Open notepad the same way by right clicking it and choosing Run as Administrator. Then you should be able to save the files.

Comment: JUST A QUICK POINT: Dont edit the index.php file in the `\wamp\www` folder. That is the WAMPServer home page. If you change that the home page wont work. Create a subfolder in the \wamp\www folder and play in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exit wampserver and run again by right clicking the wampserver and choose `run as administrator`. Then you should be able to stop and start the services. 
Open notepad the same way by right clicking it and choosing `Run as Administrator`. Then you should be able to save the files.

Comment: WAMPServer does not need to be run using `Run as Administrator` it runs as Local System account quite happily.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to raouf Athar. later in the tutorial it said that notepad++ needs to run as administrator to change these files, and it seems that instead of saying "needs administrator", notepad simply says that another program is using the file.

thanks to all who tried to help me

Comment: You only need to run your editor `as Administrator` to edit the `\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file. This is because that file is protected by windows itself to prevent local DNS poisoning by malware.